# Reference parent from iframe to apply function to iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I looked around here and found this script to reference a parent from an iframe:

```
$(parent.document.body)
```

But how would I right a script that says, if the body of the parent has a certain class, 
make a link within my iframe go to a certain destination?

My iframe lives on the same server as the parent. I'm using this script once the parent body.class is defined:

```
$("#some-link").attr('href','entrant-list.html');
```

Just to be clear - my script lives in iframe, looks for class in parent doc, then sets a url on an element within iframe based on what class it found in parent doc.

Just need some help with the final code. Thank you.

Comment: As a side comment - what is stopping you from passing a query string to your iframe src parameter when loading the iframe? and then accessing those url variables.

Comment: Because a link in the iframe changes, but the iframe source is constant.  Passing a different src would get me a different file, which is not desired. Am I hearing you right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your iframe, have an onready script that does the following:

```
$(function(){
    var pBody = $(parent.document).find("body")
    if(pBody.hasClass("foo")){
        $("#some-link").attr("href", "bar.com");
    } else if(pBody.hasClass("foo2")){
        $("#some-link").attr("href", "bar2.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks logical, but is not working for me. It doesnt seem to want to call the link from the script. Ive doublechecked my classes, and still nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok its working. I removed it from the function and just let it run on ready. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!